# How can SSL work with "subdomain" but not "subdomain.subdomain.domain.com"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, internal-dns

I'm investigating an SSL setup and Chrome says the cert was issues to, `subdomain.subdomain.domain.com` but if I visit that URL I get the "Cert Invalid" warning". Yet, if I visit "subdomain" directly, the cert is accepted. I'm not 100% how you even setup a site to not have a ".com/org" etc let alone get SSL to work in this sense. Does anybody have any ideas/experience with how this might be setup/possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subdomain.subdomain.domain.com` is a little bit confusing. Unifying might help for explanation:

A subdomain is every part left of the most right dot. Only the most right part (`com`) is no subdomain. It is a Top Level Domain (TLD).

Terminology:

```
subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com
       |         |        |    |
       |         |        |     \---> TLD: Top Level Domain
       |         |         \--------> SLD: 2nd/Second Level Domain
       |          \----------------->      3rd/Third Level Domain
        \--------------------------->      4th/Fourth Level Domain
```

**Every certificate is issued for only one CN** (Common Name).

In case the CN is the 3rd Level Domain `subdomain.domain.com`, Chrome will work only with this domain without errors.

Every additional subdomain needs to be added as [Alternativ Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name). Otherwise you will get an error. A common usecase is the `www.` subdomain which is added as [Alternativ Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name).

Multiple domains could be added. It is possible to get a certificate for mydomain.net (CN) with multiple Alternative Names included like: `www.mydomain.net`, `smtp.mydomain.net`, **`my-other-domain.com`** and **`www.my-other-domain.com`**

As mentioned above, Alternative Names do not have to belong to the same "domain".

Wildcard Certificates like `*.google.com` are another option without propagating "all your domains" to public. [Data for every issued certificate will be accessible for everyone.](https://crt.sh) ([e.g. %.google%.com](https://crt.sh/?q=%.google%.com) resolves google, googlemail, googleapis,...)

Comment: So I'm guessing that this is an "Alternative Name" as the cert would have `*.subdomain.domain.tld`, but how is it that navigating to `subdomainA.subdomainB.domain.tld` has an SSL error, but going direct to `subdomainA` is secure? I don't even understand the DNS portion of having `subdomainA` resolve correctly. If i type something in the browser window without http it usually results in a google search, but with this, I can just type `subdomainA` and it resolves to `https://subdomainA` and is secure.

Comment: Please check the DNS resolution with a ping to subdomainA and subdomainA.subdomainB.domain.tld.
 Both should ping the same ip address. When typing only one word to the browser, it does not know you mean a domain. A domain typical includes at minimum one dot. So you have to prepend http:// or https://

Comment: Exactly, but somehow, when I type just "subdomainA" it resolves to "https://subdomainA" and I can't figure out how. @MaxxFlow

Comment: sometimes there's browser internal guessing what you want to do. The browser history is involved too. If you were at `https://subdomainA` before, then you your browser assumes a good choice. Even it is a possibility that [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is or was configured at the Webserver. Then your browser **knows** the website must be opened via https and there is never a try for http. You could use `curl -I https://subdomainA/` for testing at a console, which gives you the website header or a ssl-error. curl doesn't have any caching like normal browsers

Answer (score 0):

What had happened is we have a self-signed cert for "subdomain" and a public/ca signed cert for "subdomain.subdomain.domain.tld". We were using the self signed cert. When I switched to the public cert, only the proper URL would work for SSL.